# android 10 is not working on BLE Bluetooth connection

Tags: android

android 10 for BLE Bluetooth connection is not connected , i will set all permission also but i get connection status 133 issues ,how to solve this issues ,here i declare the scanning and callback code ,please check and give your idea

but below android 10 version is working fine,only issues on android 10 device ,give an idea to solve the issues

```
private void scanLeDevice(final boolean enable) {
           if (scanner == null) {
               scanner = btAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();
           }
           if (scanCallback == null) setScanCallback(null);
       scanner.startScan(createScanFilters(),createScanSettings(),scanCallback);
          isScanning = true;
       }


        ScanCallback scanCallback = new ScanCallback() {
               @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
               @Override
               public void onScanResult(int callbackType, @NonNull ScanResult scanResult) {
                  if (connectedDevices.containsKey(scanResult.getDevice().getAddress())) {
                      return;
                   }
                   if (connectingDevices.contains(scanResult.getDevice().getAddress())) {
                       // If we're already connected, forget it
                       //Timber.d("Denied connection. Already connecting to  " + scanResult.getDevice().getAddress());
                       return;
                   }
                   if (connectionGovernor != null && !connectionGovernor.shouldConnectToAddress(scanResult.getDevice().getAddress())) {
                       // If the BLEConnectionGovernor says we should not bother connecting to this peer, don't

                       return;
                   }

                   final BluetoothDevice device = btAdapter.getRemoteDevice(scanResult.getDevice().getAddress());
                   if (device == null) {
                       Log.e(TAG, "Device not found.  Unable to connect.");
                   }
                   connectingDevices.add(scanResult.getDevice().getAddress());
                   // connectToDevice(device);
                   Timber.d("Initiating connection to " + scanResult.getDevice().getAddress());

                   device.connectGatt(context, false, mGattCallback, BluetoothDevice.TRANSPORT_LE );

               }

               @Override
               public void onScanFailed(int i) {
                   Timber.e("Scan failed with code " + i);
               }
           }; 



      @NonNull
       BluetoothGattCallback mGattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {
           @Override
           public void onConnectionStateChange(@NonNull BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
               synchronized (connectedDevices) {
                  // It appears that certain events (like disconnection) won't have a GATT_SUCCESS status
                   // even when they proceed as expected, at least with the Motorola bluetooth stack
                   if (status != BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS)
                       Timber.w("onConnectionStateChange with newState %d and non-success status %s", newState,    gatt.getDevice().getAddress());

                   Set<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> characteristicSet;

                   switch (newState) {
                       case BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTING:
                           Timber.d("Disconnecting from " + gatt.getDevice().getAddress());

                           characteristicSet = discoveredCharacteristics.get(gatt.getDevice().getAddress());
                           for (BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic : characteristicSet) {
                               if (notifyUUIDs.contains(characteristic.getUuid())) {
                                   Timber.d("Attempting to unsubscribe on disconneting");
                                   setIndictaionSubscription(gatt, characteristic, false);
                               }
                           }
                           discoveredCharacteristics.remove(gatt.getDevice().getAddress());

                           break;

                       case BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED:
                           Timber.d("Disconnected from " + gatt.getDevice().getAddress());
                           connectedDevices.remove(gatt.getDevice().getAddress());
                           connectingDevices.remove(gatt.getDevice().getAddress());
                           if (transportCallback != null)
                               transportCallback.identifierUpdated(BLETransportCallback.DeviceType.CENTRAL,
                                       gatt.getDevice().getAddress(),
                                       Transport.ConnectionStatus.DISCONNECTED,
                                       null);

                           characteristicSet = discoveredCharacteristics.get(gatt.getDevice().getAddress());
                           if (characteristicSet != null) { // Have we handled unsubscription on DISCONNECTING?
                               for (BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic : characteristicSet) {
                                   if (notifyUUIDs.contains(characteristic.getUuid())) {
                                       Timber.d("Attempting to unsubscribe before disconnet");
                                       setIndictaionSubscription(gatt, characteristic, false);
                                   }
                               }
                           } else
                           if ( status != BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS ) {

                               if ( status == 133) {
                                   refreshDeviceCache(gatt);

                               }

                           }
                           gatt.close();                         discoveredCharacteristics.remove(gatt.getDevice().getAddress());
                           break;
                       case BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED:
                           boolean mtuSuccess = gatt.requestMtu(BLETransport.DEFAULT_MTU_BYTES);

                           Timber.d("Connected to %s. Requested MTU success %b", gatt.getDevice().getAddress(),
                                   mtuSuccess);
                           break;
                   }

                   super.onConnectionStateChange(gatt, status, newState);
               }
           }

           @Override
           public void onMtuChanged(@NonNull BluetoothGatt gatt, int mtu, int status) {
               Timber.d("Got MTU (%d bytes) for device %s. Was changed successfully: %b",
                       mtu,
                       gatt.getDevice().getAddress(),
                       status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS);

               mtus.put(gatt.getDevice().getAddress(), mtu);

               // TODO: Can we craft characteristics and avoid discovery step?
               boolean discovering = gatt.discoverServices();
               Timber.d("Discovering services : " + discovering);
           }

           @Override
           public void onServicesDiscovered(@NonNull BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
               if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS)
                   Timber.d("Discovered services");
               else
                   Timber.d("Discovered services appears unsuccessful with code " + status);
               // TODO: Keep this here to examine characteristics
               // eventually we should get rid of the discoverServices step
               boolean foundService = false;
               try {
                   List<BluetoothGattService> serviceList = gatt.getServices();
                   for (BluetoothGattService service : serviceList) {
                       if (service.getUuid().equals(serviceUUID)) {
                           Timber.d("Discovered Service");
                           foundService = true;
                           HashSet<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> characteristicSet = new HashSet<>();
                           characteristicSet.addAll(service.getCharacteristics());
                           discoveredCharacteristics.put(gatt.getDevice().getAddress(),    characteristicSet);

                           for (BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic : characteristicSet) {
                               if (notifyUUIDs.contains(characteristic.getUuid())) {
                                   setIndictaionSubscription(gatt, characteristic, true);
                               }
                           }
                       }
                   }

                   if (foundService) {
                       synchronized (connectedDevices) {
                           connectedDevices.put(gatt.getDevice().getAddress(), gatt);
                       }
                       connectingDevices.remove(gatt.getDevice().getAddress());
                   }
               } catch (Exception e) {
                   Timber.d("Exception analyzing discovered services " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
               if (!foundService)
                   Timber.d("Could not discover chat service!");
               super.onServicesDiscovered(gatt, status);
           }

           /**
            * Subscribe or Unsubscribe to/from indication of a peripheral's characteristic.
            *
            * After calling this method you must await the result via
            * {@link #onDescriptorWrite(BluetoothGatt, BluetoothGattDescriptor, int)}
            * before performing any other peripheral actions.
            */
           private void setIndictaionSubscription(@NonNull BluetoothGatt peripheral,
                                                  @NonNull BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic,
                                                  boolean enable) {

               boolean success = peripheral.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, enable);
               Timber.d("Request notification %s %s with sucess %b", enable ? "set" : "unset", characteristic.getUuid().toString(),    success);
               BluetoothGattDescriptor desc = characteristic.getDescriptor(CLIENT_CHARACTERISTIC_CONFIG);
               desc.setValue(enable ? BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_INDICATION_VALUE :    BluetoothGattDescriptor.DISABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
               boolean desSuccess = peripheral.writeDescriptor(desc);
               Timber.d("Wrote descriptor with success %b", desSuccess);
           }

           @Override
           public void onDescriptorWrite(@NonNull BluetoothGatt gatt, @NonNull BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor,
                                         int status) {

               Timber.d("onDescriptorWrite");
               if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS && transportCallback != null) {

                   if (Arrays.equals(descriptor.getValue(), BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_INDICATION_VALUE)) {
                       transportCallback.identifierUpdated(BLETransportCallback.DeviceType.CENTRAL,
                               gatt.getDevice().getAddress(),
                               Transport.ConnectionStatus.CONNECTED,
                               null);

                   } else if (Arrays.equals(descriptor.getValue(), BluetoothGattDescriptor.DISABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE)) {
                       Timber.d("disabled indications successfully. Closing gatt");
                       gatt.close();
                   }
               }
           }

           @Override
           public void onCharacteristicChanged(@NonNull BluetoothGatt gatt, @NonNull BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
               Timber.d("onCharacteristicChanged %s with %d bytes", characteristic.getUuid().toString().substring(0,5),
                       characteristic.getValue().length);

               if (transportCallback != null)
                   transportCallback.dataReceivedFromIdentifier(BLETransportCallback.DeviceType.CENTRAL,
                           characteristic.getValue(),
                           gatt.getDevice().getAddress());

               super.onCharacteristicChanged(gatt, characteristic);
           }

           @Override
           public void onCharacteristicWrite(@NonNull BluetoothGatt gatt,
                                             @NonNull BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {

               Timber.d("onCharacteristicWrite with %d bytes", characteristic.getValue().length);
               Exception exception = null;
               if (status != BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                   String msg = "Write was not successful with code " + status;
                   Timber.w(msg);
                   exception = new UnknownServiceException(msg);
               }

               if (transportCallback != null)
                   transportCallback.dataSentToIdentifier(BLETransportCallback.DeviceType.CENTRAL,
                           characteristic.getValue(),
                           gatt.getDevice().getAddress(),
                           exception);
           }

           @Override
           public void onReadRemoteRssi(@NonNull BluetoothGatt gatt, int rssi, int status) {
               super.onReadRemoteRssi(gatt, rssi, status);
           }

       };
```

Answer (score 0):

now the app is working for change the bluetooth device support type

```
            device.connectGatt(context, false, mGattCallback, BluetoothDevice.DEVICE_TYPE_LE);
```

but now the app is not working on huawei device , if any have idea for the device huawei for this issue

Comment: public static final int DEVICE_TYPE_LE = 2;
    public static final int TRANSPORT_LE = 2;

Does that really make a difference? Both are having same value